# Cross site scripting -REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest-service

I got a vulnerability test result on a REST API connecting with FAcebook Front end.
This is my result,and i dont have a clue where i should look into to fix this.Can anyone help please

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>
> boundary=---------------------------23565553918837
>
> Content-Length: 1391
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN" np.JGCEKoVGeQwkxpbdVv1TDaZyovqVMRg_ksRVNsHpE.yyKMlX92SZIvU8FyTPLJL0qCCGJVC45lKfohIDpfGl.BtJoMhcz9MuLOrFe05yruDhnmrElQukbytJ5ssiBdK5FvS73Jr5sKECgfMy_CHZqPNY=
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cancelURL" /015E0000002OT8M
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id" 015E0000002OT8M
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="retURL" /015E0000002OT8M
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="save_new_url" /p/doc/DocumentUploadUi?retURL=%2F015E0000002OT8M&pid=005E0000004530H
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sts" upd
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utype" 0
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="logo.html" Content-Type: text/html alert('Vulnerable')
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="docURL"
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="save"
>   Replace Document
>
> -----------------------------23565553918837--

Comment: This takes us to no where, provide more details please - your request object/response whatever can help ?